# jQuery fails to change value of SELECT element

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have strange problem with jquery. I want to change data of select element but for some reason it won't change it. Does someone knows why it won't change?

Here is code:

```
function getData(){
    //$(document).ready(function() {
    $.ajax({
            url: "php/formData.php",
            success: function(data) {
                try {

                    var parsed = JSON.parse(data);
                    $(document).ready(function() {
                    $("#DATA0").val(parsed.name);
                });


                } catch(e) {
                    alert("Error: " + data);
                }
            },
            error: function(data) {
                bootbox.alert("Error: " + data.statusText);
            }
        });

}
```

HTML:

```
<select id="DATA0" class="form-control">
<option value="X"></option>
<option value="Data1">Some data</option>
<option value="Data 2">Some data</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Any error at console???

Comment: @Manwal nope. I tried code in console too but without luck...

Comment: What is return from this call  "php/formData.php"

Comment: @Kamruzzaman it return data that is inside select option element

Comment: please give a example of return data, Like ["value1","value 2"] or [{"name":"value1"},{"name": "value2"}]

Answer (score 1):

Your code is not getting called as document is already loaded.You do not need to wrap the code in dom ready. simply use:

```
$("#DATA0").val(parsed.name);
```

### Demo

Comment: @jureispro: what is the value of `parsed.name`?

Comment: @I tried with simple string like "KKKK" and it wont change data. parsed.name is defnied and it displays ok in console (console.log used)

Comment: the value you are trying to set to should be the value of option.

Comment: hmm maybe there is problem in encoding... I am using special characters so maybe that's the problem

Comment: @jureispro, Maybe you have multiple problems, but the fact that you're using `.ready()` inside the ajax callback is definitely enough for this not to work.

Comment: @PeterHerdenborg I used that because someone mention it that it need to be wrapped inside .ready() .

Comment: @jureispro, true, but it's the code that's calling `getData()` that needs to be wrapped inside .ready(), or at least you should wrap the whole ajax call. Since the Ajax call in itself will delay execution of the callback, .ready() will already have fired before you register the listener for it.

Comment: definitely you shouldn't be using that in ajax as the event is already fired.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried (temporarily) creating another element and seeing if you have populate it with the value of parsed.name?  I ask because it looks like if you get a value like "KKKK" or something like that it doesn't match any of the options in your select statement - so I'm not sure anything would change.  (Because none of the existing items have a value that matches what you got back from your ajax call.)

If, on the other hand, you created a text box (with an ID of "mytextbox"), you try something like this:

```
$('#mytextbox').val(parsed.name);
```

Comment: It seems more straightforward to use `console.log(parsed.name)` or `alert(parsed.name)`

Comment: Completely agree.  Only suggested it because Milind indicated earlier that he'd already seen his expected values when he used console.log().  And because I don't think trying to assign a value that doesn't already exist in the select element is going to work.  Whereas providing it to a text box would (and at that point he could decide if he wanted to use that element instead).

Answer (score 0):

I think you have called function getdata() before the page achieves its ready state so by that when the ajax get into its success function, it doesn't have #DATA0 tag id. So for this you can use following code:

```
function getData(){
$.ajax({
        url: "php/formData.php",
        success: function(data) {
            try {

                var parsed = JSON.parse(data);
                $("#DATA0 option[value="+parsed.name+"] ").prop("selected",true);


            } catch(e) {
                alert("Error: " + data);
            }
        },
        error: function(data) {
            bootbox.alert("Error: " + data.statusText);
        }
    });
}
```